# How to remove a body in Processing

Tags: processing

This should be easy but I may be misunderstanding something fundamental.

I have ellipses (called movers) on a screen in box2d. The ellipse is represented by a body. The body has a variable r which I use to make the ellipse size.
I want to destroy the ellipse when the r=0.

This is what i have written:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < movers.length; i++) {
  if(movers[i].r<0){
      box2d.destroyBody(movers[i].body);
  }
}
```

However this gives me an assertion error at the line `box2d.destroyBody(movers[i].body);`

How do I correct this? Is this because I am destroying the body but not the ellipse possibly or some other subtlety?

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is not intuituitive but for future reference the problem is that box2d gets confused when trying to kill bodies if it is done inside of a world timestep.

What does this mean?

It means that you have to add all the bodies you are using to an arrayList rather than an array and your code should work from that. If you do that then at the end of `void draw` you can add the following (where movers is an arrayList of objects which have bodies and r is an attribute which defines whether a body should be destroyed or not):

```java
for (int i = movers.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  Mover p = movers.get(i);
  if (p.r<0) { //r is whatever attribute of your body 
    movers.remove(i);
  }
}
```

This will destroy the bodies by removing them from the arrayList you are working from